# What is a robust approach to deleting a CKRecord associated with an IndexPath in a table view or collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cloudkit, ckrecord

Basically to delete the cell "offline" I use this method so that whenever you swipe from right to left the user can delete the tableview cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        self.polls.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

However, it obviously doesn't affect the `CKRecord` of the cell content I created before. So how can I fetch and delete the `CKRecord` data at the exact row the user swiped-to-delete on?

Comment: It depends on your model. What is `polls` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `polls` is the data source array declared as `[CKRecord]` you have to do three things.

1. Get the record from the data source array at the given index and remove it from the appropriate `CKDatabase`.
2. Remove the record from the data source array (you're already doing that).
3. Delete the row in the table view calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` passing `[indexPath]`.

For example (`publicDatabase` is the actual `CKDatabase` instance):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
       let record = polls[indexPath.row]
       publicDatabase.deleteRecordWithID(record.recordID, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
          // do error handling
       })
       polls.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
       tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

For proper error handling you might have to put the code of step two and three into the completion block.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
       let record = polls[indexPath.row]
       publicDatabase.deleteRecordWithID(record.recordID, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
          if error != nil {
             // do error handling
          } else {
             self.polls.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
             }
          }
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, polls is the data source array (I wasn't sure how to call it)

The problem is that I don't really know how to get the record from polls at the given index. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: One issue I see with this is the row is removed from the table view even if the record isn't deleted from CloudKit successfully. There are a few possible ways to deal with this. One might be to reinsert the row if the deletion fails. Another might be to only delete the row from the table view once it is successfully deleted from CloudKit. But that might be confusing to the user.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, thanks. I added an alternative.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to ensure the call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` is done on the main thread. Also keep in mind that the indexPath could change due to other changes to the table during the time it takes to delete the record from CloudKit. It's far from a trivial situation.

Comment: @rmaddy OK, but at least I added the crucial main thread dispatch.